# "driver cannot be resolved" in Java program

Tags: java, selenium, automation, appium, helper

I'm new to the programming world so I wouldn't know how to fix this.

```
`@Test
public void LoginEmail() {

    driver.findElement(By.id("email_button")).sendKeys("xxxxxxxx@gmail.com");`
```

At driver.findElement , driver is underlined red. When I hover over it these are my options.

Couldn't copy the options, so I took a screenshot:

[image: Couldn't copy the options, so I took a screenshot]

Comment: Where did you declare `driver` ?

Comment: The only other places where I mentioned driver are in this line in my code : **AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), cap);**

Comment: Ok, you initialized it...but Ivan is asking where

Comment: @DamoneWilliams you cannot acces the driver from that test method. You either need to declare either in method or test initialization method. On a sidenote, you should probably be mocking the driver if you aren't directly testing it.

Comment: Declare and Initialize the driver first. Then the issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

you should initialize it first :

```
 try {
    WebDriver driver = new AndroidDriver();

    // And now use this to visit Google
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");

    // Find the text input element by its name
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

    // Enter something to search for
    element.sendKeys("Cheese!");

    // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element
    element.submit();

    // Check the title of the page
    System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());
    driver.quit();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Comment: The only other places where I mentioned driver are in this line in my code : **AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("localhost:4723/wd/hub"), cap);** So should "driver be "AndroidDriver"?

Comment: Yes it is, I updated my example code see it then u'll find how to use that

Answer (score 0):

AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("localhost:4723/wd/hub"), cap); 
This should be a class or local accessibility. Declare as a class object i.e in this text fixture or in the parent class which is inherited by this class or initialize locally i.e. in the test method.